# “There is a little point in doing anything about it.”

Tags: sentence-meaning

> There is a little point in doing anything about it.

This sentence is completely unclear to me. I’ve been trying to translate it, but it is nonsense in my native language. Could you explain the meaning of the sentence in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be:

> There is little point in doing anything about it.

Here *little point* meaning is like *little reason* or *not a lot of reason*, as in:

> There is **not a lot of reason** in doing anything about it.

It is between *no reason* (not doing something) and *good reason* (possibly doing something).
A "reason" is the case you would make to do something, in the context of this sentence.

Comment: Can we say There is not a lot of reason in doing anything **for** it whit the same meaning?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It depends on what "it" is, and the larger context. "for it" probably only works with living things ("for him", "for the cat", etc.).